# Kafka Streams Do Not Restart with Aggregated Values

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am aggregating values on a stream like so:

```
private KTable<String, StringAggregator> aggregate(KStream<String, String> inputStream) {
    return inputStream
            .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
            .aggregate(
                    StringAggregator::new,
                    (k, v, a) -> {
                        a.add(v);
                        return a;
                    }, Materialized.<String, StringAggregator>as(Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("STATE_STORE"))
                            .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                            .withValueSerde(getValueSerde(StringAggregator.class)));
}
```

Normally, this works perfectly. However, when the application is restarted the aggregated value for the keys is lost. Additionally, there's also a possibility that the entire server will be terminated and a new one (with a new version of the streams application) will come online. How can I ensure that the values for the aggregation persist?

Comment: Your code looks correct and the aggregation value should be preserved. Unclear to me, why you might lose data. Is the store changelog topic created? Do the logs show anything suspicious?

Comment: Yeah, the store topic is created and the logs look pretty normal.

Comment: Hmmm... Have you tried to call `.withLoggingEnabled()` ? Also, you can simplify and only pass the "STATE_STORE" name instead of the supplier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating aggregation logic which uses the aggregation result which has been persisted on a kafka topic. Here's the logic:

```
private KStream<String, StringAggregator> getAggregator(String topicName, 
                                                        KStream<String, String> input,
                                                        KTable<String, StringAggregator> aggregator) {

    return input
            .leftJoin(aggregator, (inputMessage, aggregatorMessage) -> { 
                if (aggregatorMessage == null) { 
                    aggregatorMessage = new StringAggregator(); 
                }
                aggregatorMessage.add(inputMessage);
                return aggregatorMessage; 
            }).peek((k, v) -> logger.info("Aggregated a join input for {}: {}, {} aggregated.", topicName, k, v.size()));
}
```

Here's the logic for actually building the stream.

```
String topicName = "input";
KStream<String, String> input = streamsBuilder.stream(topicName);
KTable<String, StringAggregator> aggregator = streamsBuilder.table("aggregate");
getAggregator(topicName, input, aggregator).to("aggregate");
```